# Bash wildcard working in command line but not script

Tags: bash, macos

I've a basic `ls` command I'm running in my command line `$ ls [root]/*`, from which I can see the contents of my `$root` directory. But, when I run the same command in a script, I see this error: `ls: [root]/*: No such file or directory`. I'm going to paste the script below, but is someone able to tell why the command is running fine in the command line but not the script? Thank you.

```
#! /bin/bash

root="[root]"
ls "$root/*"
```

**edit:**

I tracked down the problem. The wildcard should *not* be inside the double quotes unless I'm looking for a file or directory with that name. The script below runs successfully.

```
#! /bin/bash

root="[root]"
ls "$root/"*
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: I'm running the script from the command line `$ ./[file]`

Comment: `ls [root]/*` would only do the right thing as long as you had no file or directory called `r`, `o` or `t` in the current directory.

Comment: Yes, are square brackets part of the name?! Also, if you found an answer, add it as such and later accept it. You have to wait some time I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best answer to my question was the edit I made to my question. I'll say it again.

I wanted to use an `ls` wildcard in a bash script and wrote this file:

```
#! /bin/bash

root="[root]"
ls "$root/*"
```

But, writing my `ls` this way looks for files or directories with the name `*`. In order to make use of the wildcard I need to leave `*` outside of the quotes. See the example below:

```
#! /bin/bash

root="[root]"
ls "$root/"*
```

**note:**

I'm using the square brackets `[]` in my question and answer contextually. The name of my directory isn't the literal string `[root]`, it's something else, but the square brackets let the reader understand what's being said contextually.

But maybe a fake root path or name is better in the future.

Comment: yes, we should add * outside of "" shell command

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here.

1. `[root]` is a shell globbing pattern that matches any of the three characters `r`, `o` or `t`.  If you do `ls [root]` and you happen to have a directory or file called `r`, `o` or `t`, then that pattern would expand to the name of that file or directory.

   To safely list the content of a directory whose real name is `[root]`, you would need to quote the name, which brings us to the next point...
2. A shell globbing pattern does not expand in quotes.  This means that `"[root]/*"` refers to something called `*`, literally, in the directory `[root]`.

Your script would have to look like

```
#!/bin/sh

root='[root]'
ls "$root"/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The existent answers do not solve the problem if you use complex patterns like this:

```
cp release/artifacts/${OS}/binary?(.exe) $DEST
```

Because it failed with:

```
line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

To solve that you should add the following option to the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
```